# Akka http trust all certs

Tags: scala, akka

I just want to skip the cert verification (basically the same as curl --insecure).

`versions`: scala 2.12,  akka-http 10.2.4

I have tried these but neither worked:

1. https://gist.github.com/iRevive/4a3c7cb96374da5da80d4538f3da17cb
2. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/client-https-support.html#disabling-hostname-verification

**Custom SSLContext**

```
implicit val system: ActorSystem[Nothing] = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "SingleRequest")
implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.executionContext
val noCertificateCheckContext = ConnectionContext.https(trustfulSslContext)

private val trustfulSslContext: SSLContext = {

  object NoCheckX509TrustManager extends X509TrustManager {
  override def checkClientTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String) = ()

  override def checkServerTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String) = ()

  override def getAcceptedIssuers = Array[X509Certificate]()
  }

  val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
  context.init(Array[KeyManager](), Array(NoCheckX509TrustManager), null)
  context
}
val res = Await.result(Http().singleRequest(Get(url), noCertificateCheckContext), 60 seconds)
```

`Result:`

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [60
> seconds]

**Following the official doc:**

```
      implicit val system: ActorSystem[Nothing] = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty,"SingleRequest")
      implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.executionContext
      val noCertificateCheckContext = ConnectionContext.httpsClient(getConnection _)

      def getConnection(host: String, port: Int): SSLEngine  = {
        val engine = SSLContext.getDefault.createSSLEngine(host,port)
        engine.setUseClientMode(true)
        engine
      }
      val res = Http().outgoingConnectionHttps("localhost",4443, connectionContext = noCertificateCheckContext)
      val response = Await.result(Source.single(Get(url)).via(res).runWith(Sink.head), 60 seconds)
      val responseString =Await.result(Unmarshal(response).to[String], 60 seconds)
      println(responseString)
```

**Result:**

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [tried your "Custom SSLContext" reproducer](https://github.com/raboof/akka-http-connect-without-checking-cert/blob/9ce87707db4a1474bbf14e21263d46799e621115/Main.scala). Besides timing out, it also produced the following stack track in the logging:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS$.$anonfun$apply$2(TLS.scala:92)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.liftedTree1$1(TLSActor.scala:162)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor.<init>(TLSActor.scala:162)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.TLSActor$.$anonfun$props$1(TLSActor.scala:40)
```

Perhaps you didn't have an slf4j logger on your classpath? It should show a warning in that case. Anyway, after a look at the code this suggests the `sslContext` is `null` here. And that is indeed the case: you're already passing `trustfulSslContext` to `ConnectionContext.https` before it has been initialized. When [initializing the trustfulSslContext earlier](https://github.com/raboof/akka-http-connect-without-checking-cert/commit/0ca55a06afb83b587f592dd97358970502f7b834) it works for me.

As for your second approach: disabling hostname verification does not disable "the rest of" certificate validation. The JVM will still verify the certificate is valid - it will just no longer verify it belongs to the hostname you are connecting to. To accept invalid certificates, you do have to use a custom `SSLContext`. Your example can be [adapted to do that as well](https://github.com/raboof/akka-http-connect-without-checking-cert/blob/0e5d3669c65b13c1cf96016ce9bdf12930085ddd/Main.scala), but all other things being equal your first approach is simpler and there's no need for the additional indirection in your second approach.

Comment: Had to remove the 'engine.setSSLParameters' part but after that it works like a charm. thanks!